# Visual studio code CSS indentation and formatting

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

I'd like to know if there is any way to activate auto indent a CSS file in visual studio code with the shortcut <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>?

It's working fine with JavaScript but strangely not with CSS.

Comment: have you tried this extension ? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lonefy.vscode-JS-CSS-HTML-formatter

Answer (score 139):

Yes, try installing [vscode-css-formatter extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aeschli.vscode-css-formatter).
It just adds the functionality to format `.css` files and the shortcut stays the same <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

Comment: This one is doing the job perfectly. I tried the other one suggested by moped but everytime I saved a file, I had to save twice..

Comment: How to use this extension on windows? alt+shift+f doesn't work and and there is no 'Format Code' option when right click.

Comment: Have you restarted vs-code after the installation of the extension? Also, in what files are you trying to execute this command?

Comment: Didn't work for me. `Alt+Shift+F` still giving: *Sorry, but there is no formatter for 'css'-files installed.* afte reload. [Beautify css/sass/scss/less](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=michelemelluso.code-beautifier) worked.

Comment: Works great on Mac, (Cmd+K, Cmd+F), and didn't affect formatting of other file types using same keyboard shortcut.  Thanks

Comment: On Linux this is `Ctrl+Shift+I`

Comment: I installed it, pressed `Alt+Shift+F` and got the following message in the status line: _Extension 'TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features' cannot format 'style.css'_

Comment: Boom! Just save you css file and it formats it. This is what I was looking for thanks!

Comment: I searched for extensions `category:formatters css`, and the top download had the lowest ratings.  People were showing the `aeschli.vscode-css-formatter` extension a lot of love.  It was last updated on 11/17/2021, which makes it very current.  Worked great for me.  Perfect alternative to having nothing.  Ended my search.  Got on with work.

Answer (score 50):

[Beautify css/sass/scss/less](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=michelemelluso.code-beautifier)

to run this

enter `alt+shift+f`

**or**

press `F1` or `ctrl+shift+p` 
and then enter beautify ..

[image]

---

an another one - [JS-CSS-HTML Formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lonefy.vscode-JS-CSS-HTML-formatter)

i think both this extension uses [js-beautify](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify) internally

Comment: alt+shift+f did nothing, but typing beautify... worked.

Comment: Another way to use JS-CSS-HTML Formatter is  -> open Context Menu and choose Format Code

Answer (score 38):

Wasted an hour finding the best option.

Just putting it together, for easy reading and choosing one them.

**Notes:**

- CSS and SASS/SCSS/LESS are all related
- HTML, Javascript, Typescript, JSON - VS code is already formatting
- CSS and related - VS code is *not* formatting as of today

**Options:**

- To format css/sass/scss/less:

  - [Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode)

    - ***All css related supported, and not others, I choose this, it works great.***
- To format JavaScript/TypeScript/CSS:

  - [Beautify css/sass/scss/less](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=michelemelluso.code-beautifier)

    - *but, already JS, TS are supported by VS code*
- To format JS, CSS, HTML, JSON file (wraps js-beautify)

  - [JS-CSS-HTML Formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lonefy.vscode-JS-CSS-HTML-formatter)

    - *but, already JS, HTML, JSON are supported by VS code*
- To format CSS

  - [CSS Formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aeschli.vscode-css-formatter)

    - *but, only CSS supported, not all the related - not maintained 6+ months*

**To format:**

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> in VS Code, after installing Prettier.

Comment: Prettier lists scss, but not sass. Beautify claims to support Sass but from my experience smashes everything to a single line. (explicitly talking Sass, not Scss)

Comment: As of `15.01.21`, [prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) is the most up-to-date (last update date)

Answer (score 10):

I recommend using [Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) as it's very extensible but still works perfectly out of the box:

```
1. CMD + Shift + P -> Format Document
```

or

```
1. Select the text you want to Prettify
2. CMD + Shift + P -> Format Selection
```

EDIT: Prettier has become vastly more popular and standardized since I first posted this answer. It has gone so far as to even be used directly in the build flows of [most modern frontend projects](https://prettier.io/en/users/). I strongly encourage users looking to format their code use the Prettier VSCode extension, which [tries to use the same settings configured by said build flows](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode#visual-studio-code-settings).

Comment: Or simply use `Alt + Shift + F`. I also found Prettier to be best.

Answer (score 6):

After opening local **bootstrap.min.css** in visual studio code, it looked unindented.
Tried the commad **ALT+Shift+F** but in vain.

Then installed

> **CSS Formatter** extension.

Reloaded it and **ALT+Shift+F** indented my CSS file with charm.

Bingo !!!

Answer (score 4):

There are several to pick from in the gallery but the one I'm using, which offers considerable level of configurability still remaining unobtrusive to the rest of the settings is [Beautify by Michele Melluso](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=michelemelluso.code-beautifier). It works on both CSS and SCSS and lets you indent 3 spaces keeping the rest of the code at 2 spaces, which is nice.

You can snatch it from [GitHub](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify) and adapt it yourself, should you feel like it too.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a little bit late to the party but this might help users using `prettier`. Just add this line to the `setting.json` file.

```
"[css]": {
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
}
```

Save and all should be good now

Answer (score 3):

Go to Files menu -> Preference -> Extentions 
Then type CSS Formatter wait for it to load and click install

Answer (score 1):

Install HookyQR.beautify extension. It will beautify your javascript, JSON, CSS, Sass, and HTML in Visual Studio Code. It is the most use extensions for this purpose

Answer (score 1):

[Beautify](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify) ([Github](https://github.com/HookyQR/VSCodeBeautify)) & [Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) ([Github](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode)) are the best plugin for web development in Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score -8):

To format the code in Visual Studio when you want, press:
(Ctrl + K) & (Ctrl + F)

The auto formatting rules can be found and changed in:
Tools/Options --> (Left sidebar): Text Editor / CSS (or whatever other language you want to change)

For the CSS language the options are unfortunately very limited.
You can also make some changes in: .../ Text Editor / All Languages

Comment: Question  is for Visual Studio Code (VSCode) not Visual Studio