# VS code - How to auto format CSS?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, autoformatting

I'm new to VS code and have been searching for a way to auto format CSS when saving data. Surprisingly, I can't seem to find any good extension or well-explained site of how to auto format CSS in VS code.

HTML is formatted the moment I saved a file, and want to do the same thing on CSS.

Ideally I want the one like "Beautify" that can be used in Atom.

Any advice?

Comment: Duplicated question, try this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37740690/1723397

Comment: A built-in formatter may be in v1.66, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71623907/836330.

Answer (score 6):

Quite sure you can do this with [prettier code formatter plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode). And you can set format on save true for all languages by adding the following to your user settings json file(dont forget to reload vscode after updating) :

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
```

you can enable format on save for a specific language by adding the following too :

```
"[css]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

Comment: What if I only want a formatter for CSS and nothing else? For JS, JSON, HTML I already have a formatter.

Answer (score 0):

```
"[css][scss][less]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.css-language-features"
}
```

The JSON configuration you've provided appears to be related to Visual Studio Code (VSCode) settings for formatting CSS, SCSS, and LESS code. This configuration sets the default formatter for these languages to "vscode.css-language-features."

Here's what this configuration does:

"editor.defaultFormatter": This setting in VSCode allows you to specify the default code formatter for a particular language or file type.

"vscode.css-language-features": This value indicates that you want to use the built-in CSS language features of VSCode as the default formatter for CSS, SCSS, and LESS files.

In simpler terms, when you open or edit CSS, SCSS, or LESS files in VSCode, it will use its own internal formatter for those languages by default.

You can customize your VSCode settings by adding or modifying settings in your settings.json file to tailor your development environment to your preferences. This particular configuration is useful if you prefer to use the VSCode built-in formatter for CSS-related languages.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**