# Does Visual Studio Code have a builtin formatter for CSS?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

VS Code's builtin language features can format HTML, JS, TS, and JSON. You can use these settings:

```json
"[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
},
"[javascript][javascriptreact][typescript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
},
"[json][jsonc]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.json-language-features"
}
```

I saw in the [HTML docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html#_formatting) that VS Code uses [js-beautify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-beautify/v/1.13.0) under the hood. `js-beautify` can also format CSS. However, if I open a CSS file, and run the the command "Format document with", it does not offer a builtin formatter. Am I right in thinking that there is no builtin CSS formatter then?

There is no mention of this in the [CSS docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/css).

It seems a bit strange considering that for HTML files, the CSS in style tags is formatted.

Comment: You can use `JS-CSS-HTML Formatter` extention.

Comment: The [reviews for JS-CSS-HTML Formatter extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lonefy.vscode-JS-CSS-HTML-formatter&ssr=false#review-details) say it has major issues

Comment: Solutions go in answers, not in edits to the question. I recommend undeleting your answer.

Answer (score 2):

See [GH issue: [css] provide css formatter](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/19166) one is probably coming to v1.66 (it is in Insiders now).

and enable:

`CSS > Format: Enable` enable/disable the default css formatter, enabled is the default option

Other options:

`CSS > Format: Newline Between Rules` Separate rulesets by a blank line.
`CSS > Format: Newline Between Selectors` Separate selectors with a new line.
`CSS > Format: Space Around Selector Separator` Ensure a space character around selector separators '>', '+', '~' (e.g., `a > b`).

[image: built-in css formatting options]